# User's persistence not storing in localStorage, firebase and react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me figure this out. So I'm authenticating with Firebase and I wanted to store user persistence so that users don't have to consistently sign in when they are not yet logged out.

Here's my code before applying Firebase documentation for "Currently signed users"

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import logo from '../../assets/logo.png'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

import './login.css'
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'


import { 
    signInWithEmailAndPassword,
} from "firebase/auth";

const Login = () => {

  const [email, setEmail] = useState();
  const [password, setPassword] = useState();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();

  const from = location.state?.from?.pathname || "/dashboard";


  const signIn = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((result) => {
        navigate(from, { replace: true});
      })
      .catch((error) => {
       alert("Invalid Credentials: Please Confirm the email and password is entered correctly.")
      });
  };
```

After applying Firebase documentation for "Currently signed users" to store user persistence, here's the updated code:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import logo from '../../assets/logo.png'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

import './login.css'
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'


import { 
    signInWithEmailAndPassword,
    getAuth, 
    onAuthStateChanged,
} from "firebase/auth";

const Login = () => {

  const auth = getAuth();
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentState) => {
      setUser(currentState)
    })
  }, [])
  
  

  const [email, setEmail] = useState();
  const [password, setPassword] = useState();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();

  const from = location.state?.from?.pathname || "/dashboard";


  const signIn = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((result) => {
        const user = result.user;
        setUser(user);
        navigate(from, { replace: true});
      })
      .catch((error) => {
       alert("Invalid Credentials: Please Confirm the email and password is entered correctly.")
      });
  };
```

Still, when I refresh my dashboard, I still get signed out which would require always signing in. I would really appreciate it if this can be sorted out. Thanks a bunch!